# In CSS, briefly flash the bg of an element

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I am making a dirt simple web page, with simple functionality in vanilla JavaScript. Every now and then I change the `innerHTML` of a `<span>`. Is there an easy way to “flash” this span? That is, the background should briefly turn — for example — red, and then fade back to the default white background. Just to alert the user that a thing updated.

I would like to do this in modern, simple CSS, because I want to learn more about that. I'm sure I could manually animate all this, but I want to know if there's a modern way to do it. Presume I'm using a modern web browser. This is an internal tool, I don't need to support every web browser. But I'd rather use standard compliant approaches.

Comment: You could add a CSS class to the span and also fire a setTimeout() to remove that class from the span. If you want to go fancy, you can add transition to it. You can also use this ready made utility https://animate.style

Comment: The fact that the color should change when the contents of the element have changed means that you cannot simply use CSS, there will need to be some JavaScript along with it.

Answer (score 4):

Since the flashing of the `<span>` element is triggered by a change in its contents, CSS alone cannot suffice to achieve the functionality. You'll also need to use a bit of JavaScript, to be able to trigger the color change when the contents have changed. A [CSS Transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions) on the element will take care of the rest (i.e the fade-in and fade-out animations).

Here is a simple code snippet (supports your "modern web browser") that illustrates how it can be done with the use of [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) to delay the second animation (otherwise, the change will be instantanious).

```js
function updateContent(element, content) {
    // update content
    element.innerHTML = content;
    // change the background color (will trigger the CSS configured transition)
    element.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    // change the background color back (with a delay equal to transition length)
    setTimeout(() => { element.style.backgroundColor = 'white'; }, 500);
}

// delayed initial update (just to better visualize what's happening)
setTimeout(() => {
    updateContent(document.getElementById('flashy'), 'new content');
}, 1000);
```

```css
#flashy {
    background-color: white;
    transition: background-color 500ms linear;
}
```

```html
<span id="flashy">initial content</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you had shared your code here then I could have helped you better but anyways
You can Do that kind of things with the help of CSS `transition` property.
It is really handy for doing things like these.

[For more Info on transition property check this.](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition-property.asp)